# Django Restframework - How to send a Contact-Me-Email using gmail(SMTP) without using models or forms, and still get validation?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-email

On my website that I am building I have a simple form:

[contact me form from my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1A8V.png)

I am using `ReactJS` to build the frontend and as backend I am using Django `Restframework`.

In my `views.py` I have the following code:

```
class SendEmailView(APIView):
    def post(self,request):
        subject = request.data['subject']
        message = request.data['message']
        email = request.data['emailAddress']
        if len(subject)<5:
          
            raise ValidationError('Subject must be at least 5 characters long.')
        if len(message)<10:
             raise ValidationError('Message must be at least 10 characters long.')
        try:
            send_mail(subject=subject, message=message, from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, recipient_list=[email], fail_silently=False)
            return Response({"success":True})
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception: ', e.message)
        
            return  Response({'Exception: ', str(e)},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I just was experimenting a bit. But what I mainly doing here is I get the subject, message and email from the POST request and then send the email, which works perfectly.
The thing that I cannot make work is that the view sends `ValidationErrors` as json to my frontend `ReactJs` app.

For example, if the subject and / or message is too short... or if its not a valid email.
I want to send back corresponding errors in the form of (or something similar)

> {'errors':[{email:"not a valid email"}, {"subject":"The subject must
> contain at least 5 letters. You provided only 3."}]}.

The thing is I am not using Django forms or Django Models here... if so, there would tons of tutorials and it would not be a problem.

In other words I am using Django `Restframework`, so I am not utilizing form validation and I do not have a model, because I do want to safe anything to the database.

Do I have to write my own validation logic, etc.?

Thanks a lot!